# Can't install package from file, Last metadata expiration check, Error: Unable to find a match, Centos 8

Tags: docker, installation, centos8

tell me please what I am doing wrong. I can't install package from file.

Earlier, I tried to install by pointing to the address, but

```
dnf install https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:44 ago on Tue 23 Mar 2021 09:06:41 PM UTC.
containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb                                       1.0 MB/s |  27 MB     00:27    
Can not load RPM file: /var/cache/dnf/commandline-a76fe31ae310b0c7/packages/containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb.
Could not open: /var/cache/dnf/commandline-a76fe31ae310b0c7/packages/containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb
```

I have downloaded file and try dnf and yum to install

```
sudo dnf install /tmp/containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:13:47 ago on Tue 23 Mar 2021 08:47:58 PM UTC.
No match for argument: /tmp/containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb
Error: Unable to find a match: /tmp/containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb
```

I tried

```
yum clean all
```

I have added docker repo

I worked on CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011

Answer (score 0):

For me it's works, try this step-by-step:

```
sudo dnf update
sudo yum update
sudo dnf clean all
sudo yum clean all
```

and after this try to install package